SP size not changing when device text size changes on some Pixel devices
I'm having a problem with font scaling that happens only on some pixel devices. For some of my views that contain a text, i'm setting the view height in sp. The reason for this is that i'm using the height of these views in some calculations and i need them to be fixed, but i can't use dp because otherwise text could get cut. So I use sp so that my view would expand when i change the device's text size.
This approach works on most devices, but i've noticed that on my pixel 8 (Android 14), when i change the text size, the views stay the same height. Only the texts inside the views expand which causes them to get cut and look horrible.
I've tried logging the actual value of the height and i can see that on other devices, they change, but on pixel 8 they don't. For example:
On other devices, with default text size, 52sp equal 160 and when i scale up the font, 52sp changes to 223. But testing on Pixel 8, the value for 52sp is always the same, regardless of text size.
Does anybody know why this happens and how exactly does Pixel 8 handles font scaling? And also if there's a way to be able to solve my problem?
For the sake of clarity, here's a sample xml I'm trying to make work:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="52sp"
    android:id="@+id/container">
    
    ...
    Other views
    ...

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/border_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    ...
    Other views
    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>    


Why are you setting the height that way at all?  This is what wrap_content is for-  it will expand as your data expands.

I needed the height to be a fixed height because of the layout that i have. I had to do some calculations based on this fixed value.
But considering the change to Android 14, i'm gonna have to use wrap_content and come up with a solution to work with it.

It looks like my problem is with the new Android non-linear font scaling feature. With this feature, font scale values are no longer a traditionally fixed value and they're flexible and non-linear which makes using sp for padding, height, etc deprecated.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features#non-linear-font-scaling
the function TypedValue.applyDimension() now checks for a fontScaleConverter value and if it exists, it tries to convert the sp value the non-linear way rather than the traditional way.

